# multiple field search in dajngo app wrong results

Tags: python, html, django, forms, search

I would like to create a multiple field search for the my database in django app.
my search work correct only if the user use **all** fields from html form.

if the user don't use some field or if some field is empty or blank
then my query return all results (like `apps=movies.objects.all()` ) and that is wrong because the user in not required to use all fields 
but anytime to use fields where need for search.

any idea how to fix that ?

here my code:

models.py :

```
class category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class movies(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    code_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    movies_title=models.ForeignKey('category', blank=True, null=True)
    link=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

html form :

```
<form method="POST" action="{%url 'search'  %}">{% csrf_token %}
  <select name="link">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">link 1</option>
    <option value="1">link 2</option>
    <option value="2">link 3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="category">
    <option value=""></option>
    {% for data in cat%}
    <option value="{{ data.id }}">{{ data.title }}</option>
 {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <select name="year">
    <option value=""></option>
        {% for data in apps%}
    <option value="{{ data.id }}">{{ data.year }}</option>
 {% endfor %}
  </select>
    code: <input type="text" name="code"><br>
    code_2: <input type="text" name="code_2"><br>
    name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

views.py :

```
def search_erga(request):
    apps=movies.objects.all()
    cat=category.objects.all()
    template='movies.html'

    query_link=request.GET.get('link')
    query_category = request.GET.get('category')
    query_year=request.GET.get('year')
    query_code = request.GET.get('code')
    query_code_2=request.GET.get('code_2')
    query_name = request.GET.get('name')

    if any(
        (
            query_link is not None,
            query_category is not None,
            query_year is not None,
            query_code is not None,
            query_code_2 is not None,
            query_name is not None,
        )
    ):
        apps_1=movies.objects.filter(link__icontains=query_link,
                                   movies_title__icontains=query_category,
                                   year__icontains=query_year,
                                   code__icontains=query_code,
                                   code_2__icontains=query_code_2,
                                   name__icontains=query_name)

        context={
            'apps':apps,
            'cat':cat,
            'apps_1':apps_1
        }
    else:
        context={
            'apps':apps,
            'cat':cat,
        }


    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Please look at how forms work in Django; you're doing tons of unnecessary work right now. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/

Comment: You should also post  `movies.html`. How do you handle `apps` and `apps_1`? Did you notice that you always return `apps` which includes all results? Is this intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `apps_1` as mentioned in the above comments - and rename it `movies`.

You want to break down the if tag.

For example:

```
if query_link != None or query_category != None:
    filters...
```

This means that if `query_link` is None and `query_category` isn't, you'll end-up looking for apps that do not have a query link.

What you want to do instead is:

```
movies = Movie.objects.all()

if query_link:
    movies = movies.filter(link__icontains=query_link)

if query_category:
    movies = movies.filter(movies_title__icontains=query_category)

...
```

---

In Python & Django, you can rely on simple conditions such as `if query_link:`. You don't need `if query_link != None`. Python does what you would expect. In other languages you would have to check if it's not null and not an empty string; Python does it for you. This works for Django many 2 many fields as well. For example, if `user.memberships:` is enough (no need to check if the variable is set and if there is at least one membership)...